# Weka exercise in choosing best algorithm

Tags: methods, weka

I have some data on a csv file in numeric form, with data like amount of hours spent sleeping, working... And also binary data such as whether I have had an exam or not. With all these data I'm trying to predict how many hours I've spent watching TV today. The thing is that I'm not very sure as to which WEKA algorithm or method may be best? Since I'm trying to predict a numeric value and there are some variables that are numeric and others binary....I'd appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to bin this regression problem into a classification problem, ie maybe you can increment in 30 min intervals.

Another thing to consider is the amount of precision you are expecting in this regression, I mean does it make sense for your classifier to be able to distinguish between 10 mins of TV vs 11 mins of TV? If would assume not, but then again, it depends on your application.

Also, how many instances of data do you have? And how varied is the dataset? I would suggest using a simple Naive Bayes classifier first, since it's less prone to overfitting, than say Random Forest (when the amount of data is this low).